# create first user in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

This is my first time using `Laravel 5`. Never experienced with any of other framework like CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Yii, etc. I just know how to use make api REST with `slim framework`.

I already create a table `users` as I can't access `<<URL>>/home`. I create fields and load it some data. Whenever I want to try reset the password, it show error because I dont have table `password_resets`. What are the steps to be taken after install the Laravel actually.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create any table manually (and you shouldn't). In Laravel you have [migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations) that help you quickly create tables in your database and [seeds](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations#database-seeding) (where you can put initial data to those tables).

In fresh Laravel installation you have 2 ready migrations (for creating `users` and `password_resets` tables). All you need to do is running your console, go to directory where you have your Laravel project and run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

to run those migrations. After running this command Laravel will create those 2 tables for you. Before, you need to have configured your database connection (look at `config/database.php` file)

Comment: i hope this might help somebody else because i couldnt find this in the official docs